# Why does Windows Terminal in Windows 11 doesn't resolve environment variables when opened using context menu?

Tags: windows-11, windows-terminal

I've used `sysdm.cpl` to set the following two environment variables system-wide:

```
JAVA_HOME=%ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk-8
M2_HOME=%ProgramFiles%\Apache\maven
```

When starting a Windows Terminal using the context menu of Windows Explorer on an arbitrary directory, those environment variables are not properly resolved:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

Installieren Sie die neueste PowerShell für neue Funktionen und Verbesserungen! https://aka.ms/PSWindows

PS C:\[...]> cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2134]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

C:\[...]>set
[...]
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\THS
JAVA_HOME=%ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk-8
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\THS\AppData\Local
M2_HOME=%ProgramFiles%\Apache\maven
NVM_HOME=C:\Users\THS\AppData\Roaming\nvm
NVM_SYMLINK=C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

When starting a Windows Terminal using the Windows Search, those variables are resolved:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

Installieren Sie die neueste PowerShell für neue Funktionen und Verbesserungen! https://aka.ms/PSWindows

PS C:\Users\THS> cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2134]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

C:\Users\THS>set
[...]
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\THS
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-8
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\THS\AppData\Local
M2_HOME=C:\Program Files\Apache\maven
NVM_HOME=C:\Users\THS\AppData\Roaming\nvm
NVM_SYMLINK=C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

The interesting thing is that `PSModulePath` is properly resolved in both cases. The following is set in `sysdm.cpl`:

```
PSModulePath=%ProgramFiles%\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
```

While the followin is readable in per-dir terminal...

```
PSModulePath=C:\Users\THS\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
```

vs. a terminal opened using the Windows Search:

```
PSModulePath=C:\Users\THS\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
```

Any explanation for this? Thanks!

Comment: Since making these environment variables changes, have you restarted Explorer (or logged out and back in)? Or have rebooted?

Comment: Yes and changing the variables is reflected instantly when not using the context menu and just opening a terminal using Windows Search as well.

Comment: I think I'm missing something - in this instance, why does it matter if `%ProgramFiles%` is listed or it's resolved to `C:\Program Files` - unless using Powershell, which wouldn't recognize `%%` variables? _(you're opening `cmd`, so I'm a bit confused)_

Comment: It matters because not all apps recursively resolve environment variables in paths on their own, havin `%ProgramFiles%\some\dir` in e.g. `PATH` doesn't make EXEs in that dir available to the shell etc. In my case, e.g. Maven isn't found and if it's found because of having a proper path in `PATH`, it doesn't work e.g. because of wrong `JAVA_HOME` and stuff. This is simply not how the environment is expected to be.

Comment: Which version of the Terminal are you using? There was a pretty major re-write of how the Terminal handles env vars in Terminal 1.18 (the preview build of the terminal at time of writing). That might help?

Comment: I'm using the default one installed with a most current, non-insider Windows 11: 1.17.11461.0. I might wait for new releases then, not expecting too much that such basics get fixed at all. :-/

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug in Windows (or rather inconsistency),
which you can signal via the Feedback Hub, but fixing it is
up to Microsoft.

You may for the moment avoid using such variables as
`%ProgramFiles%`.
After all, the value of this variable will never change.

Comment: I see the same behaviour with cusomt other environment variables as well. It would be helpful if you could try to repoduce, Feedback Hub ist mostly useless anyway.

Comment: General behavior means a general bug, for which you can only search for workarounds. For example, you could perhaps add your own context-menu item that will call a `.bat` file which will use the [start command](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) to run Terminal. This might (hopefully) avoid the bug.